# how to put/update all json attribute from jsonArray

Tags: json, scala

I have a json like this:

```
[
    {
        "firstName":"Pierre",
        "age":"20",
        "timestamp": "123"
    },
    {
        "firstName":"Jack",
        "age":"20",
        "timestamp": "123"
    },  
    {
        "firstName":"Olive",
        "age":"20",
        "timestamp": "123"
    },  
    {
        "firstName":"Tom",
        "age":"20",
        "timestamp": "123"
    }
]
```

I would like to update all attributes timestamp to 456. I then create a code like this:

```
   import org.json.simple.{JSONArray, JSONObject}

   myJsonArray.forEach {
      obj =>
        val jsonObject = obj.asInstanceOf[JSONObject]
        val jsonMap = jsonObject.asInstanceOf[java.util.HashMap[String,Any]]
        jsonMap.put("timestamp",456)

    }
```

but I get at compilation:

```
Error:(31, 7) missing parameter type
      obj =>
```

Do you have any idea? Or any else implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is corrupted, there should be one comma after `"age":"20"` field.
So after Correcting it you can use following to update your JSON. Here I have used jackson liberary for JSON parsing.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val str = "[{\"firstName\":\"Pierre\",\"age\":\"20\",\"timestamp\":\"123\"},{\"firstName\":\"Jack\",\"age\":\"20\",\"timestamp\":\"123\"},{\"firstName\":\"Olive\",\"age\":\"20\",\"timestamp\":\"123\"},{\"firstName\":\"Tom\",\"age\":\"20\",\"timestamp\":\"123\"}]"
//convert JSON string to Map(String,String) 
val jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(str, classOf[Array[Map[String, String]]])
//Overwrite the key time-stamp in the given Map
val changedMap = jsonMap.map(_ ++ Map("timestamp" -> "466"))
//Convert the Map again to string
val jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(changedMap)

println(jsonString)
//output
//[{"firstName":"Pierre","age":"20","timestamp":"466"},{"firstName":"Jack","age":"20","timestamp":"466"},{"firstName":"Olive","age":"20","timestamp":"466"},{"firstName":"Tom","age":"20","timestamp":"466"}]
```

Comment: Do you have any idea if I want to get a JSONARRAY despite a json String?